# Animation Delayed for navigationBar "hidesBarOnSwipe"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

Hi everyone I have a `UITableViewController` that hides the navigation bar when the user writes the tableView

```
navigationController? .hidesBarsOnSwipe = true
```

When the user shows the navigationBar by scrolling down the tableview, the navigationbar's slide animation appears to be delayed showing a black space between the tableView and the navigation bar

How can you solve this problem?

Here you can see what happens when the navigation bar is shown after the user scrolls down

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try in `viewDidLoad` in your `UITableViewController`

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: I tried but it keeps leaving a black space when the position of the navigation bar changes while scrolling

This happens when I switch from "EnterBackground" to "Become Active"